# bootstrap table doesnot display data

Tags: mysql, bootstrap-table

[image]i want to fetch data from mysql on basis of unique id. then display this data in bootstarp table.

```js
$('#Modal').modal('toggle');
 var row_id = $('#id').val();
 $.ajax ({ 
            url: "test.php",
            data: { id : row_id },
   method:"POST",
   //async: false,
   dataType:"json",
            success: function( result ) {
                
   var obj=result;
   
   var obj1=JSON.parse(obj);
   
   //table
   $('#table1').bootstrapTable('load', obj1);
   var $table = $('#table1');
       $table.bootstrapTable({
      search: true,
         pagination: true,
         buttonsClass: 'primary',
         showFooter: true,
       minimumCountColumns: 2,
    columns: [{
        field: 'num',
        title: 'ID'
    }, {
        field: 'first',
        title: 'firstname'
    }, {
        field: 'second',
        title: 'second Name'
    }, {
        field: 'three',
        title: 'last name'
    }, {
        field: 'four',
        title: 'father name'
    }, {
        field: 'five',
        title: 'Gender'
    }, {
        field: 'six',
        title: 'class'
    }, {
        field: 'seven',
        title: 'total marks'
    }, {
        field: 'last',
        title: 'percentage'
    }],
    data: obj
});
            }
   
        });
```

i have followed this example https://www.sourcecodesite.com/use-bootstrap-tables-display-data-mysql.html. but the problem is my data is not displaying. table is empty on loading

my php code that will display data

```js
<?php 
 //require 'db.php';
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");  
 
 if(isset($_POST['id']))  
 {  
   $sqltran = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '".$_POST['id']."'")or die(mysqli_error($con));
  $arrVal = array();
   
  $i=1;
   while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltran)) {
          
      $name = array(
        'id' => $rowList['id'],
            'first'=> $rowList['A'],        
        'second'=> $rowList['B'],
        'three'=> $rowList['C'],
        'four'=> $rowList['D'],
        'five'=> $rowList['E'],
        'six'=> $rowList['F'],
        'seven'=> $rowList['G'],
           'last'=> $rowList['H']
           );  
 
 
       array_push($arrVal, $name); 
   $i++;   
   }
     echo  json_encode($arrVal);     
 
 
   mysqli_close($con);
 } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to edit your code like this:

```
var $table = $('#table1');
$table .bootstrapTable('load', obj1);
 $table.bootstrapTable({
                  search: true,
                  pagination: true,
                  buttonsClass: 'primary',
                  showFooter: true,
                   minimumCountColumns: 2,
    columns: [{
        field: 'num',
        title: 'ID'
    }, {
        field: 'first',
        title: 'firstname'
    }, {
        field: 'second',
        title: 'second Name'
    }, {
        field: 'three',
        title: 'last name'
    }, {
        field: 'four',
        title: 'father name'
    }, {
        field: 'five',
        title: 'Gender'
    }, {
        field: 'six',
        title: 'class'
    }, {
        field: 'seven',
        title: 'total marks'
    }, {
        field: 'last',
        title: 'percentage'
    }],
    data: obj
});
            }

        });
```

Comment: Change your data: obj to data:obj1 and follow my previous script. Im using phone so its hard for me to type 

Comment: thanks @McBern i have corrected that there is some other problem iam  uploading my php file as well. kindly look at that and guide mw

Comment: where is your php file?

Comment: try to remove JSON.parse just use result directly

Comment: change your id column to this -> columns: [{
        field: 'id',
        title: 'ID'
    },

Comment: thanks mcbern but i have tried all of this i do not understand what is the problem. i have worked with bootstrap tables before but do not get wht is problem this time